# Flutter Appbar action call child class function

Tags: flutter

I have a TextFormField() and a listview() in a screen, which build by 2 different stateful class:
homePage.dart and
homeBody.dart

Inside homepage.dart, there is a Clear all data button in Appbar

When click it, will trigger the homeBody.dart 's clear TextFormField() value and clear list[] 's function()

How to clear all data inside the child class from the parent class

Below is my code and
[dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/16983383d0db480e86e5916fcf35b616?)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'test',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'Example',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19.0),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              tooltip: 'Clear All Data',
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.clear_all,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                //HomeBody().onClear();  //this has error
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: HomeBody());
  }
}

class HomeBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeBodyState createState() => _HomeBodyState();
}

class _HomeBodyState extends State<HomeBody> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  List<String> litems = ["1", "2", "Third", "4"];
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void clearAllData() {
    _controller.clear();
    litems = [];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
          child: TextFormField(
            controller: _controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: litems.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int Index) {
                  return new Text(litems[Index]);
                }))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: You can pass `GlobalKey` to `HomeBody` and get `_key.currentState` then call `homeBodyState.clearAllData();`

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
              onPressed: () {
                final _HomeBodyState homeBodyState = _key.currentState;
                homeBodyState.clearAllData();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: HomeBody(key: _key));
  }
...
class HomeBody extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeBody({Key key}) : super(key: key);
```

Step 2: You need to call `setState`

```
void clearAllData() {
    _controller.clear();
    setState(() {
      litems = [];
    });
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'test',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'Example',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19.0),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              tooltip: 'Clear All Data',
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.clear_all,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                final _HomeBodyState homeBodyState = _key.currentState;
                homeBodyState.clearAllData();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: HomeBody(key: _key));
  }
}

class HomeBody extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeBody({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _HomeBodyState createState() => _HomeBodyState();
}

class _HomeBodyState extends State<HomeBody> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  List<String> litems = ["1", "2", "Third", "4"];
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void clearAllData() {
    _controller.clear();
    setState(() {
      litems = [];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
          child: TextFormField(
            controller: _controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: litems.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int Index) {
                  return new Text(litems[Index]);
                }))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```